# On second glance, at second glance, on a second glancing, etc

Tags: idioms

Unfortunately, I've seen all of these being used in very similar contexts:

> On second glance
>
> On a second glance
>
> On a second glancing

I'm asumming there's no different for this idiom no matter the ordinal number, so it should be "at second glance".

The sentence in question is:
On a second glancing through that list...

Should it be "At second glance through that list"?

Comment: According to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+second+glance%2C+at+second+glance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20second%20glance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20second%20glance%3B%2Cc0), At second glance is more common, but both are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Glancing* is not used in this idiom, as may be seen from [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+second+glance%2Cat+second+glance%2Con+second+glancing%2C+at+second+glancing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20second%20glance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20second%20glance%3B%2Cc0):

[image: A Google ngram chart showing "at second glance" and "on second glance" to roughly parallel each other at a near 45 degree incline since 1890, with "at second glance" generally outpacing "on second glance".]

If you are going to employ a preposition phrase such as *through the list* modifying "glance", idiomatic usage calls for a determiner: *At/on **a/the** second glance through the list*.

Moreover, any ordinal beyond *first* strikes me as odd with *glance*. A first examination may be no more than a glance; but I would expect that if something impels a second look the subsequent examination will be more thorough.

Comment: Yeah, it almost seems like someone's mixing up "on second thought" and "at first glance".

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is "at first glance" or "at the/a first glance", so I would choose "at the second glance" and I would go on with the preposition "at", not "through (this list)".